# loop through files in dir, ordered by created date

Tags: node.js

I'm new to NodeJS and need some help, I an using this code to get / loop through all files in a dir (and sub dirs), I want the newest file (created date) to be at the to of the array, is that possible?

```
var walk    = require('walk');
var files   = [];
var walker  = walk.walk('./test', { followLinks: false });
walker.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
    files.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stat contains the info i needed, and then I sorted by this ..

```
files.reverse(function(a,b) {
        aa = new Date(a.mtime).getTime();
        bb = new Date(b.mtime).getTime();
        return aa - bb;
    });
```

But now i deal with ... CEST and CET ... but that will be another day ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `walk` module, it doesn't appear so.  And it doesn't look like the `stat` argument has that information either.  However, as you're looping through, you can look up the `ctime` & etc using [`fs.stat`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats).  That's the most direct method I see to get at what you're after.  You won't be able to put it at the end of the loop, but you can rearrange the loop based on that info, depending on what your end goal is.

Comment: Stat contains the info ... and i already got it to work .. Now I just fight with the CEST and CET ... not easy to compare! :(